# {"timestamp": 1567422726395,"status": 404,"error": "Not Found","message": "No message available","path": "/SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate/add/" }

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I tried to make a CRUD RESTapi using SpringBoot, Java, Mysql. My code are okay and running in eclipse but when I tried to POST data from POST Man to mysql workbench it always shows the error.

Project name: SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate
    My pom.xml file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>springmvc_example</groupId>
      <artifactId>SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Problem in POSTMAN
```

POST: localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate/add/
   This ERROR MESSAGE is displaying every time:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1567422726395,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate/add/"
}

Main Project codes:
src/main/java:
 package: springmvc_example.application


class: UserApplication.java
 package springmvc_example.application;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class UserApplication {

  public static void main(String[]args) {
  SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
            }

        }


 Codes for configuration. 
Package: springmvc_example.config
class: HibernateConfig.java


        package springmvc_example.config;

         import java.util.Properties;
         import javax.sql.DataSource;
         import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
         import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
         import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
         import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
         import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
         import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
         import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
         import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
         import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;  

        @Configuration
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        @ComponentScan({ "springmvc_example.config" })
        public class HibernateConfig {  

    @Bean
         public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean(){
         LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
         sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
         sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "springmvc_example.model" });
                  sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());


     return sessionFactoryBean;
             }



    @Bean
             public DataSource dataSource(){
              DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
              ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springrestful");
              ds.setUsername("root");
              ds.setPassword("djhonseena");

              return ds;
                 }



    private Properties hibernateProperties(){
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
              properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
              properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");

              return properties;
                 }



    @Bean
             @Autowired
             public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s){
              HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
              txManager.setSessionFactory(s);

              return txManager;
                 }

                }

 Another configuration class:       
WebConfig.java


package springmvc_example.config;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan({"springmvc_example"})
    public class WebConfig {

    }



Webinitializer configuration class: 
WebInitializer.java
    package springmvc_example.config;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

    public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

         @Override
         protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
          return new Class[]{ WebConfig.class };
         }

         @Override
         protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
          return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected String[] getServletMappings() {
          return new String[]{ "/" };
         }

        }
```

Controller package and class

```
package: springmvc_example.controller
class: UserController.java
package springmvc_example.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import springmvc_example.model.User;
import springmvc_example.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {

 @Autowired
 UserService userService;

 @RequestMapping(value="/user/", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
 public @ResponseBody List getListUser(){
  List users = userService.getListUser();

  return users;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/add/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody User add(@RequestBody User user){
  userService.saveOrUpdate(user);

  return user;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
 public @ResponseBody User update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody User user){
  user.setId(id);
  userService.saveOrUpdate(user);

  return user;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public @ResponseBody User delete(@PathVariable("id") int id){
  User user = userService.findUserById(id);
  userService.deleteUser(id);

  return user;
 }

}
```

Database package and classes:

```
package: springmvc_example.dao
interface: UserDao.java
package springmvc_example.dao;

import java.util.List;

import springmvc_example.model.User;

public interface UserDao {

 public List getListUser();

 public void saveOrUpdate(User user);

 public void deleteUser(int id);

 public User findUserById(int id);

}
```

Another database class

class: UserDaoImpl.java
    package springmvc_example.dao;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import springmvc_example.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 protected Session getSession(){
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public List getListUser() {
  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);

  return (List) criteria.list();
 }

 public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
  getSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
 }

 public void deleteUser(int id) {
  User user = (User) getSession().get(User.class, id);
  getSession().delete(user);
 }

 public User findUserById(int id) {
  return (User) getSession().get(User.class, id);
 }

}
```

Model package and class:

```
package: springmvc_example.model
class: User
package springmvc_example.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;

 @Column(name="name", nullable=true)
 private String name;

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

}


package: springmvc_example.service
interface: UserService.java
package springmvc_example.service;

import java.util.List;

import springmvc_example.model.User;

public interface UserService {

 public List getListUser();

 public void saveOrUpdate(User user);

 public void deleteUser(int id);

 public User findUserById(int id);

}

class: UserServiceImpl.java

    package springmvc_example.service;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import springmvc_example.dao.UserDao;
    import springmvc_example.model.User;

    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

     UserDao userDao;



@Autowired
 public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
  this.userDao = userDao;
 }

 public List getListUser() {
  return userDao.getListUser();
 }

 public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
  userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
 }

 public void deleteUser(int id) {
  userDao.deleteUser(id);
 }

 public User findUserById(int id) {
  return userDao.findUserById(id);
 }

}
```

Properties file for mysql database connection

```
    src/main/resources
    application.properties

    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springrestful
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=djhonseena

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

    spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
    spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true

    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your request to `localhost:8080/add/`

Otherwise add a class level `@RequestMapping` annotation specifying the `value` of the endpoint.

Comment: still not working could you please check my code once, thank u for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot initializes the application the context of `/`. There's nothing mapped to `/SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate`.

To have your request working, simply send a POST to `/add/`. (since you've mapped with the slash in the end of add/, you have to send exactly with this slash (/add/)).

Now, if you need the context of `/SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate` to be used within your requests, simply put the following line in your `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/SpringRestfulWebServiceHibernate
```